# Retagging questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

As I understand it tags will be removed after some time if they're only used for one question. [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15559/wheres-the-energy-in-simulated-caps-coils) remained untagged when some tags were deleted. I wanted to retag, but the only tag I could think of was [gyrator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gyrator), which didn't exist yet.

There aren't any other questions about it, but it pops up in a number of answers. So, suggestion: if you see an interesting term in an *answer* which could help leading users to the question, add it as a tag to the question.

An alternative could be to have tags for answers, but I don't know if that's worth considering for a feature-request. What do you guyz/galz think?

Comment: Frankly, the whole world of tags here is so confusing that I just ignore them altogether.  So my answer is I don't care what they do, it won't effect me and I'll just continue ignoring tags.  There are so many, you can't easily get a list right when you need one, and I'm not sure what anyone does with them anyway.  I notice you're on a tag cleanup crusade lately.  Fine with me, but what exactly is the value anyway?

Comment: @Olin - Thanks for the encouragement! :-) Well, there's the option of leaving the mess like it is now, or trying to improve it to something useful. I'm for the latter, but it looks like I'm pretty much on my own, and yes, then it may seem useless :-(. (Say, you were at a Microchip conference, weren't you? Learned interesting new things?)

Comment: I learned that even Microchip Masters is getting dumbed down for the masses.  Is there nothing left for people that actually want to know how things really work instead of blindly calling a library written by someone that didn't have to think about system level integration?  Who is going to write those libraries of the future if nobody will be left that understands the details? Maybe that's why things have been so busy here lately, and with others I know in the same business.  We haven't been as busy as now in at least a decade.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - a primary use of tags on a larger site (see stackoverflow for example) would be to allow you to personally read only questions of interest, rather than feeling the need to close those of non-interest.

Comment: @Chris: But that would be wrong.  You don't close questions because you aren't presonally interested, you close them because they don't belong here, having nothing to do with your own level of interest.  I sometimes even give a quick answer to a question I have voted to close.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - you shouldn't, but you **do** close questions because you aren't personally interested in them, and allow that to distort your judgement of what belongs.  Don't try to argue against the ample record of your actions.

Comment: @Chris: That's a load of crap.  I close questions when I think they don't belong here.  We may disagree on our threshold for some of the criteria, but suggesting other motives is wrong.  Keep in mind that anything I voted on to close and ultimately got closed required either 4 other users or a moderator to agree.

Comment: No, it's quite simple really.  If you only gave attention to questions that you found interesting, you wouldn't be voting to close ones you find uninteresting.  And interest is an obvious and unavoidable bias on the judgement call, for everyone.

Comment: Why are we arguing on a 8 month old question?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many tags that at best only few people know of each tag's existence, hence 'missing' tags, 'duplicate' tags, 'newly invented' tags.

Upon typing a title or question, you get a number of related questions proposed that may already answer yours. I would love an automatic and intelligent tag proposal while typing the question itself just like that.